# JS doesn't update DOM only on iPhone (iOS 13)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, vue.js

I have a problem on one site which I develop. And it's only on iPhones. I test on my iPhone 11 (with iOS 13.1) - any JS file doesn't work. No matter there is an Vue or jQuery into it. On iPadOS - no problem everything works just fine.

I had use remote debugging via Safari, but console is clear. No error, warning, anything.

I tried to use polyfills (all from core/js). But even simple jQuery code doesn't work - it not updateing DOM. If I use console.log - it show modyfied element, but in DOM inspection i still see original one - nothing changed at all.

I transpiling my JS by Laravel Mix - and code works both on Desktop, Mac, iPad. Not on iPhone.

I left my development copy with source maps available for you: http://leba.dev.enet55.civ.pl
So please help figure it out - what is going on with this.

---

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/home.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/sass/custom.scss', 'public/css')
    .js('resources/js/admin/gallery.js', 'public/js/admin')
    .js('resources/js/list.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/favorites.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/facility.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/super_adm_auction.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/rooming.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/adm_rooming.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/adm_auction.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/adm_edit.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/adm_edit_descs.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/adm_edit_descs_admin.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/adm_gallery_old.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/geosearch.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/map.js', 'public/js')
    .react('resources/js/new_facility.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/facility_activation.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/new_user_form.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/search.js', 'public/js')
    .sourceMaps();
```

list.js

```
require('./common/bootstrap');
require('leaflet/dist/leaflet-src');
require('./common/list_favorites');
require('./common/map');
require('./common/cssmap');
require('slick-carousel');
require('./common/ads.js');
```

common/map.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.showMap').on('click', function (event) {
        $('#mapaDiv').toggleClass('d-none');

        var mapa = L.map('mapaDiv').setView([53.015331, 18.605700], 15);
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
        }).addTo(mapa);

        var group = new L.featureGroup([]);

        $('.wynik').each(function () {
            marker = L.marker([parseFloat($(this).attr('data-lat').replace(",", ".")), parseFloat($(this).attr('data-long').replace(",", "."))]);
            marker.addTo(mapa);
            marker.bindPopup('<h4><a href="' + $(this).attr('data-url') + '">' + $(this).attr('data-nazwa') + '</a></h4><p>' + $(this).attr('data-adres') + '</p>');
            group.addLayer(marker);
        });
        mapa.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
        if (group.getLayers().length < 2) {
            mapa.zoomOut();
        }

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

list.blade.php

```
@extends('base')

@section('title', ucfirst($seo['title']))
@section('meta_keywords', 'keywords,')
@section('meta_desc', ucfirst($seo['desc']))

@section('head_css')
@endsection

@section('js')
    <script src="/js/list.js"></script>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mt-2">
            <nav aria-label="breadcrumb" class="d-none d-md-block">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('home') }}">Strona główna</a></li>
                    @if ($category && $entry)
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a
                                    href="{{ route ('category_show', ['category' => $category->slug]) }}">{{ $category->name }}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page"><a
                                    href="{{ route('listSingle', ['category' => $category->slug, 'entry' => $entry->slug]) }}">{{ $entry->name }}</a>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                    @if ($secondCategory && $secondEntry)
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a
                                    href="{{ route ('category_show', ['category' => $secondCategory->slug]) }}">{{ $secondCategory->name }}</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page"><a
                                    href="{{ route('listDouble', ['category' => $category->slug, 'entry' => $entry->slug, 'secondCategory' => $secondCategory->slug, 'secondEntry' => $secondEntry->slug]) }}">{{ $secondEntry->name }}</a>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                </ol>
            </nav>
            <h1 class="lista_h1 mt-2 mb-0">{{ ucfirst($seo['h1']) }}</h1>


            @if(!empty($entry))
            @if(!empty($entry->info))
            <div class="opis_podkat">{{ $entry->info }}</div>
            @endif
            @endif

            <div class="sort">Uwaga: wyniki pokazują się w porządku alfabetycznym od losowo wybranej litery</div>
{{-- <!-- <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
@if(!empty($entry))
{{ $entry->desc }}
@endif
            </div> --> --}}
        </div>
    </div>
    @if ($data->count() > 0)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 mt-2 mb-2">
                <a href="#" class="showMap btn btn-info float-right text-md-right">Pokaż na mapie</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 mt-2 mb-2 d-none" id="mapaDiv">
                <div id="mapa"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please may you put all relevant code in the question? Links don’t last. See [mcve]

Comment: Ok, I just add an example with jQuery code which doesn't work.

Comment: Today I have oportunity to check this on Android. It doesn't work too.